# Como aumentar a largura de um JComboBox?

Tags: java, swing

Como faço para aumentar a largura de um `JComboBox` em Java? O layout que estou usando é o seguinte:

```
setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));
```

Answer (score 1):

O `FlowLayout` utiliza o preferred size do componente:

```
int largura = 100;
int altura = 21;
seuComboBox.setPreferredSize( new Dimension(largura,altura) );
```

Answer (score 0):

Tente isso.

```
comboBox.setMaximumSize( comboBox.getPreferredSize() );
```